# RMI - Threadpool child threads socket permission issue

Tags: java, redis, threadpool, rmi

I've a Threadpool whose scheduled threads access the redis pool and perform some query with it.

I create the JedisPool instance as static in a class in which ThreadPool is created.
 I pass the JedisPool instance as a parameter while constructing each task. My constructor will be `public TestTask(DataSource ds, JedisPool pool, int xx, int yy)`. Since the task also requires a mysql connection I pass an instance of mysql connection pool's datasource. All these files are in a "packagen".

My server.policy file is in "/home/raja/parent_to_package/" directory and looks like this,

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/raja/parent_to_package/" {

permission java.security.AllPermission;

permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:*","connect,resolve";

};

grant codeBase "file:/home/raja/parent_to_package/packagen/" {

permission java.security.AllPermission;

permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:*","connect,resolve";

};
```

I run the program from parent_to_package directory like

```
java  -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/home/raja/parent_to_package/interface.jar -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.1 -Djava.security.policy=/home/raja/parent_to_package/server.policy  -Xmx256m -Xms256m packagen.MainClass
```

Still I get the following exception from the child threads.

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:22)
        at packagen.TestTask.run(TestTask.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:573)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:570)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:6379 connect,resolve)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:513)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:105)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.connect(Jedis.java:1657)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool$JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisPool.java:63)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:20)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: What does this have to do with RMI?

Comment: I could run the individual prog that gets a connection from JedisPool and perform the query. When I schedule it as a Runnable in a Scheduler with RMI and its server.policy, I got the permission issue. Of course, I may get the same exception when I don't have RMI.  Pls help.

Comment: so it is a security manager problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your codeBase specifications are correct given you are using a jar file,and I don't think your SocketPermissions are correctly specifying the host:port either. Check the documentation.